# Array dentro de un Scanner

Tags: java, arraylist, objeto, scanner

Se me pide que tras un bucle de 4 vueltas en un Scanner, luego lo inserte dentro de un array ya generado anteriormente.

El caso es que no se si lo estoy escribiendo bien o tengo que salirme del bucle para insertar después.

Os dejo el código. Gracias:

**(...)

```
   for(int i=0;i<numeroCoches;i++){
    System.out.println("Ingrese marca: ");
    String marca = entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.println("La marca es: " + marca);
```

(...)

```
    //creamos un objeto coche con los datos obtenidos
    
   Coche c1 =new Coche(marca, modelo, Integer.parseInt(año),matricula);
   garaje.add(c1);
   Coche c2 =new Coche(marca, modelo, Integer.parseInt(año),matricula);
   garaje.add(c2);
}
entrada.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

soy nuevo también en java, pero en principio entiendo que estas pidiendo todos los datos (marca, modelo, año, matricula) dentro de ese bucle, y luego quieres añadir un coche nuevo con los datos pedidos (uno por cada vuelta del bucle realmente). Lo que no entiendo es la creación de dos coches que haces luego...

```
    for(int i=0;i<numeroCoches;i++){
        System.out.println("Ingrese marca: ");
        String marca = entrada.nextLine();
       //resto de peticiones
       /*
        Coche c =new Coche(marca, modelo, Integer.parseInt(año),matricula);
       garaje.add(c);
        */
        garaje.add(new Coche(marca, modelo, Integer.parseInt(año),matricula));

    }
    entrada.close();
```

Con eso debería bastar si estoy entendiendo bien lo que estás intentando hacer. Si no es esto lo que buscabas (cosa probable), te pediría que expliques mejor el problema que estás teniendo, que entre que soy nuevo y tal ,puede que no me este enterando bien

Comment: Gracia!
Pongo los coches porque es un bucle de 4 repeticiones, entonces no se si tengo que estanciar 4 coches objeto, o con uno solo es suficiente.

Comment: Buenas. Con el código que te paso realmente estás instanciando n coches, donde n=numeroCoches, solo que, en lugar de introducirlo en un objeto coche propiamente dicho, lo estas directamente introduciendo en la lista de coches: garaje.add(new Coche(marca, modelo, Integer.parseInt(año),matricula));
Luego como es logico,para acceder a cada instancia que has creado puedes hacerlo con garaje.get(index) o como mejor te convenga para lo que tenga que realizar tu código.
Si tienes alguna otra cuestión sobre esto déjalo por aquí que le echo un ojo a menudo. Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

En estos dos códigos, se le pide al usuario que ingrese la cantidad de coches que desea guardar en la lista, luego en cada iteración se le va pidiendo los cuatro datos necesarios para crear una instancia de Coche, la cual es agregada a la lista. Al terminar, en la lista se encuentran todos los coches creados a partir de los datos pedidos al usuario.

Utilizando arreglos:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de autos: ");
        int numeroCoches=Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());
        Coche[]garaje=new Coche[numeroCoches];
        int i=0;
        while(numeroCoches>i){
            System.out.print("Ingrese marca: ");
            String marca=entrada.nextLine(); 
            System.out.print("Ingrese modelo: ");
            String modelo=entrada.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Ingrese año: ");
            int anio=Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());
            System.out.print("Ingrese matrícula: ");
            String matricula=entrada.nextLine();
            garaje[i]=new Coche(marca, modelo, anio,matricula);
            i++;
        }
        entrada.close();
         for(int j=0;j<numeroCoches;j++){
            System.out.println(garaje[j].ToString());
        }
    }
}
class Coche{
    String marca;
    String modelo;
    int anio;
    String matricula;
    Coche(String marca, String modelo, int anio, String matricula){
        this.marca=marca;
        this.modelo=modelo;
        this.anio=anio;
        this.matricula=matricula;
    }
    String ToString(){
        return this.marca+" "+this.modelo+" "+String.valueOf(this.anio)+" "+this.matricula;
    }
}
```

Utilizando ArrayList:

```
    ArrayList<Coche>garaje1=new ArrayList<Coche>();
        System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de autos: ");
        int numeroCoches1=Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());
        while(numeroCoches1>0){
            System.out.print("Ingrese marca: ");
            String marca=entrada.nextLine(); 
            System.out.print("Ingrese modelo: ");
            String modelo=entrada.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Ingrese año: ");
            int anio=Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());
            System.out.print("Ingrese matrícula: ");
            String matricula=entrada.nextLine();
            garaje1.add(new Coche(marca, modelo, anio,matricula));
            numeroCoches1--;
        }
        entrada.close();
        System.out.print(garaje1);
```

Comment: Gracias!

La duda que tengo es si el programa solo instanciando una vez la clase coches y añadiendo el arrayList con garaje.add, guarda todos los coches registrados.

Por otro lado haría despues de eso un bucle que recorra todo el array y muestre los datos registrados.

Comment: Si deseas imprimir en consola los datos, pudieras utilizar: `garaje1.forEach((c)->System.out.println(c.ToString()));`, el método `ToString` creado en la clase Coche, no es una camisa de fuerza, lo implementé para que fuera más legible a la hora de imprimir los valores del objeto. En cuanto a lo primero que planteas, no creo que sea una buena idea, pero a lo mejor alguien más tenga una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Creo que si intentas hacer eso, es decir: si creas una instancia antes del for, luego modificas los valores de sus atributos y la introduces en el ArrayList, entonces en la próxima iteración del ciclo, no solo introducirá el Coche que deseas, sino que te actualizará los valores que ya tenías en la lista, debido a que hace referencia al mismo objeto.

Comment: Gracias has sido de gran ayuda :)